# Removing only the broken package

Tags: package-management, uninstall

So  was about to install some packages so I could get programs that I want. And somehow one package got broken, I have no idea how. So now when I try to do `sudo apt-get -f install` it says broken one affects other packages. If I want to remove it, I have to remove a lot of other packages (I think even apt has to be removed) and I don't have any programs on Ubuntu that installed myself.

Is it possible to remove only the broken package or reinstall the uninstalled packages just after they were uninstalled? Remember that I don't have internet access on any Linux computer at my home right now. I am using Lubuntu 13.04.

Results of `sudo apt-get check` :

[image]

Comment: Sorry if this is really hard to understand, I can't tell it in other words

Comment: I'm going to look what does sudo apt-get check does

Comment: What exactly you tried to install?

Comment: Ive tried to install code-blocks (I downloaded every needed dependency from Ubuntu packages) here is a link if you need it: http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: What version of Ubuntu you have? Please edit your question and include that information.

Comment: Updated. Well, if nothing helps I could just freshly install 13.10 Lubuntu, but I still want to know if it's possible to remove only that package

Comment: @souravc please respond to me on that suggestion

Comment: I think you need to download this packages: http://pastebin.com/ThKxHQKK and try to install them. Otherwise, you should use sourav answer http://askubuntu.com/a/389337/169736

Comment: It should be ok, but I get this: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Building data structures... Done 
Building data structures... Done 
This package is uninstallable
Breaks existing package 'codeblocks-dbg' dependency codeblocks (= 12.11-2). oops, I think I've put them in a folder where are all of my other packages. going to try again

Comment: @Braiam You gave me bad architecture, mine isn't amd :(

Comment: Ups, just replace amd64 with i386, should be the good one

Comment: Downloading again right now, if this won't work, this will be it for today. But if it works, what should I mark as answer?

Comment: For that you should rewrite your question or ask a new one.

Answer (score 3):

Removing only broken packages was possible through **synaptic package manager**.

Run the below command on terminal to install and open synaptic,

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic && sudo synaptic
```

[image]

Right-click on the broken package and then **Mark for Complete Removal**.After that click **apply**.

Comment: when using synaptic package manager it still needs to remove all those packages

Comment: all those packages means what?

Comment: "the choosen action also affects other packages. The following changes are recuired in order to proceed" and there goes probably all packages on my computer (under "to be removed")

Comment: plz upload the screenshot.

Comment: Ok, ill just find my USB to transfer the screenshot

Comment: did you choose the broken packages or not?

Comment: take a screenshot,upload it to imgur.com and then post the link here.

Comment: Sorry, my computer froze so I took a pic of my screen(you can see everything clearly, I'm using Lubuntu newest version): http://imgur.com/XSeEaaM

Comment: did you select the broken dependencies option?

Comment: Yes, and selected complete removal too

Answer (score 1):

To see the broken packages run the following at terminal,

```
dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

After removing the broken packages to install them again, you may wish a make a list. To make a text file `broken_packages.txt` containing the list of broken packages at your home directory, use

```
dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }' > ~/broken_packages.txt
```

To remove the packages,

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Upto this uninstallation you do not need any internet access. But afterwards if you want to install them again you need to have active internet access.

Comment: Please tell me is that "-" is a minus or a dash(I'm not sure if I named it correctly)

Comment: just copy it. anyway they are same here.

Comment: Btw, won't this will make me uninstall all the packages that would uninstall with package manager?

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg -l | grep ^rc | awk '{ print $2 }'`? How many are there?

Comment: there is only one: 
codeblocks-common

Comment: what if you try `sudo apt-get purge codeblocks-common` in terminal?

Comment: Its says:  edve98@Edvino-PC:~$ sudo apt-get purge codeblocks-common
[sudo] password for edve98: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
codeblocks-contrib-dbg : Depends: codeblocks-contrib (= 12.11-2) but it is not installable
codeblocks-dbg : Depends: codeblocks (= 12.11-2) but it is not installable
libesd0 : Depends: esound-common (= 0.2.41-11) but it is not installable
Conflicts: libesd-alsa0 but 0.2.41-6ubuntu1 is to be installed
libgcc1 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-1ubuntu2) but it is not installable
libstdc++6 : Depends: gcc-4.8-base (= 4.8.2-1ubuntu2) but it is not installable
libwxgtk2.8-0-ansi : Depends: libgconf2-4 (>= 2.13.5) but it isnot installable

Comment: Depends: libjpeg62 but it is not installable
Depends: liborbit2 (>= 1:2.14.8) but it is not installable
Depends: libtiff4 but it is not installable
Depends: libwxbase2.8-0-ansi (>= 2.8.9.2) but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: That's pretty long, I hope it helped a bit

Comment: ok! have you tried `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: yes, it said that I will delete a lot of other packages (like apt, and I think this is not normal) so I didn't type "Yes, do as I say!"

Comment: I guess I will try your option after downloading the packages and installing them that Braian provided

Comment: ok go ahead and also can [look at this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/142808/127327)

Answer (score 0):

To search and destroy broken packages you can use aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
aptitude search '~B'
```

To remove them:

```
sudo aptitude remove '~B'
```

Comment: Does it come pre-installed with Lubuntu? I don't have internet connection on that computer

Answer (score -2):

try `sudo apt-get update` and see if it works

Comment: It says that it needs internet

Comment: use synaptic `sudo apt-get install synaptic`

Comment: It says I have already newest version of synaptic